# Qt and cleanup just before the application terminates

Tags: python, qt, signals, pyqt4

I have trouble doing cleanup just before the application quits - my cleanup is called before other essential events are happen.

Currently I am using

```
QObject.connect(self.qtApp,
                SIGNAL("lastWindowClosed()"),
                self._lastWindowClosed)
```

My application consists of a single `QtGui.QDialog`, that throws `SIGNAL("accepted()")` or `SIGNAL("rejected()")` (OK or Cancel buttons). If I do my cleanup as shown above, I miss those events. If I do my cleanup on `SIGNAL("aboutToQuit()")`, I do not miss those events.

I fail to discover meaningful documentation on any of the two signals. For example PySide's documentation on [aboutToQuit](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QCoreApplication.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QCoreApplication.aboutToQuit) and [lastWindowClosed](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QApplication.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QApplication.lastWindowClosed) talks about some filepths and nothing related to the lifetime of the application.

It appears that I need to use aboutToQuit(). Where can I find meaningful documentation on this signal, so that I am sure no events are missed before it?

Comment: Have a look at the standard python module [atexit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html). Probably you can use that and don't need a PyQt signal/function.

Comment: What do you mean by "miss events"? If you need to handle 2 signals, connect both of them to slots. Both slots will be called. Or do you worry about signals order?

Comment: @Riateche, yes, I worry about the signals order. One of the signals trigers some processing, while the other cleans up i.e. destroys the processing object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit` [documentation page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit):

> The signal is particularly useful if your application has to do some last-second cleanup. Note that no user interaction is possible in this state.

So if you want to do cleanup, this signal should be used.

The `lastWindowClosed` signal is emitted when all windows are closed. It doesn't necessarily lead to the application termination. And emitting this signal on application termination is not guaranteed (for example, it will not be emitted when closing application programmatically using `QApplication::quit`).

Comment: +1 Thank you. This is exactly what I needed to know. Strange that I didn't find that piece of documentation.